# How do I redirect successfully registered user to the page he was reading before login

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I've a registration system which redirects user to specific page lets say success.php

In this page I've custom script that sends out Welcome mail to the user and posts success on facebook since registration is through FB oath.

I would like to redirect success.php to the original page user was reading before asking for registration/login.

How do I do this?

I'm using Wordpress as CMS if its helpful.

Would something like this work in all situations?

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to redirect users in Wp the simplest one being :

`wp_redirect()` ([HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)) which has 2 parameters :

$location = The absolute URI to which the user will be redirected. No default.
$status = The status code to use. For example, 301, 302, etc. The default is 302.

```
wp_redirect('http://mywebsite.com/',302);
```

Note that it is also [pluggable.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions)

<strike>Then you have</strike>

```
auth_redirect();
```

which is basically the same but requires login before giving access - no parameters

you also have a [login_redirect filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) which you can use ,but i am not sure it is for your case as described.